# I get pixel perfect scrolling in native apps, but not chrome or LibreOffice, is it possible to get it?

Tags: google-chrome, touchpad, libreoffice

I'm in ubuntu 14.04 and my trackpad gives me pixel perfect scrolling in all the native apps, but not Chrome or LibreOffice, I've tried the chrome://flags smooth scrolling option, but that just animates the frankly massive jumps that scrolling gives, extensions and apps do the same thing, is there anything I can do? Do any Other browsers support it?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your first question, I don't know. As you have stated, there are libraries in Linux which support pixel perfect scrolling, so I suppose it is up to the developers to decide to use them.

As to your second question, the only browser in Linux that I've come across that supports true smooth scrolling is Epiphany (sometimes called "Web").

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Chrome or LibreOffice, but Firefox supports pixel scrolling (works in v49, not sure when it was added) if you set the `MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1` environment variable. You can set it by using `echo 'export MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1' >> ~/.xsessionrc`, for example.